# What are the benefits of using Oracle Designer?

Tags: oracle, svn, designer

Why would I want to use *Oracle Designer* as opposed to simply maintaining SQL scripts and storing them in a version control system such as *Subversion*?

I need to decide if it is worth the effort to reverse-engineer an existing database into *Designer*.
It seems like it would be easier to store *DDL* scripts along with the application source code in *subversion*.

The policy of my organization is to manage all database schemas using *Designer*.  I'm all for compliance if there is some sort of *ROI*, but I am not able to see how there would be any *ROI* by reverse-engineering an existing database into *Designer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some benefits of using Designer:

- easy to browse the table definitions, constraints etc.
- graphical tools to show tables and their relationships
- impact analysis tools
- generation of DDL for new/altered table definitions

Whether this makes its use worthwhile depends on how much your orgnaisation makes use of these benefits.  My organisation uses Designer to manage a very large (thousands of tables) database; for a smaller database the benefits may be smaller.